# Animating translation between two fixed points (Libgdx)

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx

I'm making a 2d game in libgdx and I would like to know what the standard way of moving (translating between two known points) on the screen is.

On a button press, I am trying to animate a diagonal movement of a sprite between two points. I know the x and y coordinates of start and finish point. However I can't figure out the maths that determines where the texture should be in between on each call to render. At the moment my algorithm is sort of like:

```
textureProperty = new TextureProperty();
firstPtX = textureProperty.currentLocationX
firstPtY = textureProperty.currentLocationY
nextPtX = textureProperty.getNextLocationX()
nextPtX = textureProperty.getNextLocationX()
diffX = nextPtX - firstPtX
diffY = nextPtY - firstPtY
deltaX = diffX/speedFactor // Arbitrary, controlls speed of the translation
deltaX = diffX/speedFactor
renderLocX = textureProperty.renderLocX()
renderLocY = textureProperty.renderLocY()
if(textureProperty.getFirstPoint() != textureProperty.getNextPoint()){
    animating = true
}
if (animating) {
    newLocationX = renderLocX + deltaX
    newLocationY = renderLocY + deltaY
    textureProperty.setRenderPoint(renderLocX, renderLocY)
}
if (textureProperty.getRenderPoint() == textureProperty.getNextPoint()){
   animating = false
   textureProperty.setFirstPoint(textureProperty.getNextPoint())
}
batch.draw(texture, textureProperty.renderLocX(), textureProperty.renderLocY())
```

However, I can foresee a few issues with this code.
1) Since pixels are integers, if I divide that number by something that doesn't go evenly, it will round. 2) as a result of number 1, it will miss the target.

Also when I do test the animation, the objects moving from point1, miss by a long shot, which suggests something may be wrong with my maths.

Here is what I mean graphically:

Desired outcome:
[image: Desired Outcome]

Actual outcome:

[image: Actual Outcome]

Surely this is a standard problem. I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have start coordinates X1,Y1 and end coordinates X2,Y2. And let's say you have some variable p which holds percantage of passed path. So if `p == 0` that means you are at X1,Y1 and if `p == 100` that means you are at X2, Y2 and if `0<p<100` you are somewhere in between. In that case you can calculate current coordinates depending on p like:

```
X = X1 + ((X2 - X1)*p)/100;
Y = Y1 + ((Y2 - Y1)*p)/100;
```

So, you are not basing current coords on previous one, but you always calculate depending on start and end point and percentage of passed path.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a `Vector2 direction`, giving the direction between the 2 points.
This `Vector` should be normalized, so that it's length is 1:

```
Vector2 dir = new Vector2(x2-x1,y2-y1).nor();
```

Then in the `render` method you need to move the object, which means you need to change it's position. You have the `speed` (given in distance/seconds), a normalized `Vector`, giving the direction, and the time since the last update.
So the new position can be calculated like this:

```
position.x += speed * delta * dir.x;
position.y += speed * delta * dir.y;
```

Now you only need to limit the position to the target position, so that you don't go to far:

```
boolean stop = false;
if (position.x >= target.x) {
    position.x = target.x;
    stop = true;
}
if (position.y >= target.y) {
    position.y = target.y;
    stop = true;
}
```

Now to the pixel-problem:
Do not use pixels! Using pixels will make your game resolution dependent.
Use Libgdx `Viewport` and `Camera` instead.
This alows you do calculate everything in you own world unit (for example `meter`s) and Libgdx will convert it for you.

Answer (score 0):

*I didn't saw any big errors, tho' i saw some like you are comparing two objects using == and !=, But i suggest u to use a.equals(b) and !a.equals(b) like that. And secondly i found that your renderLock coords are always being set same in **textureProperty.setRenderPoint(renderLocX, renderLocY)** you are assigning the same back. Maybe you were supposed to use newLocation coords.*

*BTW Thanks for your code, i was searching Something that i got by you <3*